# DataList Control Arrange

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, controls, datalist

I want to create DataList control and I want to have 2 columns first for "First Name" second for "Last Name". Like this:

**First Name**|**Second Name**

 
Peter &nbsp Johnson 

John &nbsp Peterson

When I try with this code, isn't working. This isn't arrange the names as I want:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="NamesDataList" runat="server" >
        <HeaderTemplate>
            First Name
            Last Name
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("FirstName")%>
            <%# Eval("LastName")%>
        </ItemTemplate>                 
    </asp:DataList>
```

I want to have DataList control like this one for example. https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/Article-Images/asp.net-img03.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:DataList ID="NamesDataList" runat="server" >
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
              <tr>
                 <td>First Name</td>
                 <td>Last Name</td>
              </tr>   
             </table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>                               
             <table>
              <tr>
                 <td><asp:Label ID="lblRaterName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>'></asp:Label> </td>
                 <td><asp:Label ID="lblRaterName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName")%>'></asp:Label></td>
              </tr>   
             </table>
        </ItemTemplate>                 
    </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: I tried like this but when I type "Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>", this return all first names in one row not one by one in separate rows like I want. How to do it to return all names one by one in separate rows ?

Comment: Add RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" in your datalist control.

Comment: Ok I understand now. One more question Repeater Control or Datalist control to use in these situations ? What do you think ?